# Retrieve Data from 3 tables and finding intersections

Tags: php, mysql

I retrieve three datasets with query1:to find new products,query2:products in sale,query3:popular products and i need to find if a products is new and in sale and also is popular or if a products only new or in sale etc. but since i limit my queries with 5 there is the possibility of not getting the same ID's at the same time.I also added the PHP code but it is logically wrong as i mentioned.What is the best of way doing that,i need your help.Thanks in advance
Query1:

```
SELECT p.`ProductID`,`TypeID`,c.CompanyID as CID,c.`Name` as CN,p.`Name`,`Picture`,`Price`,s.`SalePrice`,Count(l.ProductID) as Likes,'1' as popular 
FROM `Product` p inner join Company c on c.CompanyID=p.CompanyID inner join Likes l on l.ProductID=p.ProductID left outer join Sale s on s.ProductID=p.ProductID
where l.ts>date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and c.CompanyID in(1,2,3) group by p.`ProductID`,`TypeID`,c.`Name`,p.`Name`,`Picture`,`Price` 
order by Likes desc LIMIT 0,5
```

Query2:

```
SELECT p.`ProductID`,`TypeID`,c.CompanyID as CID,c.`Name` as CN,p.`Name`,`Picture`,`Price`,s.`SalePrice`,s.Endtime,s.Begintime,'1' as sale  
FROM `Product` p inner join Company c on c.CompanyID=p.CompanyID inner join Sale s on s.ProductID=p.ProductID left outer join SaleSizeLimit sl on sl.SaleID=s.SaleID where now()>=s.Begintime and s.Endtime>=now() and c.CompanyID in(1,2,3)  
order by s.Endtime asc  LIMIT 0,5
```

Query3:

```
SELECT p.`ProductID`,`TypeID`,c.CompanyID as CID,c.`Name` as CN,p.`Name`,`Picture`,s.`SalePrice`,`Price`,'1' as new  
 FROM `Product` p inner join Company c on c.CompanyID=p.CompanyID left outer join Sale s on s.ProductID=p.ProductID where p.ts>date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and c.CompanyID in(1,2,3) order by p.`ProductID` desc LIMIT 0,5
```

PHP CODE:

```
function Discriminate($set1,$set2,$set3) { // popular,sale,new
     $drt=array();
     $drv=0;
     if(count($set1)>0){
               $drv=1;
               $drt=$set1;
               if (count($set2)>0){
               foreach ($set2 as $p2) {
                       $interim=0;
                       $i=0;
                          foreach ($set1 as $p1) {
                              if($p1->ProductID==$p2->ProductID){
                                  $drt[$i]->Sale=1;
                                  $interim=1;
                              }
                              $i++;
                           } 


                       if($interim==0){
                           $drt[]=$p2;
                       }

                  }
               }

                $seti=$drt;

                if (count($set3)>0){
                  foreach ($set3 as $p3) {
                      $interim=0;
                      $i=0;

                          foreach ($seti as $pi) {
                             if($pi->ProductID==$p3->ProductID){
                                 $drt[$i]->New=1;
                                 $interim=1;
                             }
                             $i++;
                          } 

                      if($interim==0){
                          $drt[]=$p3;
                      }

                  }
                }


     }
     else{ // there is no new product in this company
         if(count($set2)>0){
                  $drv=1;
                  $drt=$set2;
                  if (count($set3)>0){
                      foreach ($set3 as $p3) {
                        $interim=0;
                        $i=0;
                           foreach ($set2 as $p2) {
                               if($p2->ProductID==$p3->ProductID){
                                   $drt[$i]->New=1;
                                   $interim=1;
                               }
                               $i++;
                            } 


                        if($interim==0){
                            $drt[]=$p2;
                        }

                   }
                }
         } 
         else{ // there is no sale in this company
              if(count($set3)>0){
                  $drv=1;
                  $drt=$set3;

              }  
              else{ // there is no popular product in this company
                $drv=0;
              }
         }
     }
     if($drv==1){
         return $drt;
     }
     else{
         return 0;
     }

 } // end discrimination
```

Comment: Please add spaces in your question , anyway why not using `Union`?
Wouldn't you prefer to handle in php the results you need than handling all the results and finding the "right-ones" in php?

Comment: wait a minute can i use union all three table and limit the union with a number?

Comment: As far as I can say - yes. Just add it as a limit.

Comment: but there are different fields in those queries

Comment: Start with two tables, take different names for the example and shorten the code.